# OpenCV - OpenGL - OpenCL Interop

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, opengl, computer-vision, opencl

I'm writing a very basic program to monitor performance when copying from a cv::ogl::Texture2D to a cv::ogl::Buffer (using the copyTo function), and from there to an OpenCL cv::UMat (using cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer). It seems to me on paper this should work all on the GPU but I'm having some trouble with keeping things on the GPU:

```
//OpenGL / OpenCL interop objects
cv::ogl::Texture2D cvGLTexture;
cv::ogl::Buffer cvGLBuffer;

//OpenGL texture
cvGLTexture = cv::ogl::Texture2D(cv::Size(frameWidth,frameHeight),cv::ogl::Texture2D::Format::DEPTH_COMPONENT,textureHandle,false);

//OpenGL pack PBO; set autorelease to true so the underlying OpenGL resource is destroyed
cvGLBuffer = cv::ogl::Buffer(cv::Size(frameWidth,frameHeight),CV_32FC1,cv::ogl::Buffer::Target::PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER/*,true*/);

//Copy from texture to PBO
cvGLTexture.copyTo(cvGLBuffer,CV_32F); //This should be purely a GPU copy??? But it uses a lot of CPU also

//Map PBO to OpenCL and use the UMat
//cvUMat = cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer(cvGLBuffer);    //GPU copy (does not work)
cvGLBuffer.copyTo(cvUMat);
```

The texture to buffer copy works but it uses a lot of CPU for an operation that should be only a GPU copy from what I understand.

The buffer to UMat copy only works using the OpenGL buffer's copyTo() method which is a CPU operation. The method cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer() causes a crash saying it was unable to create an OpenCL buffer.

I've verified that my GPUs (I have an integrated and a discrete one) support OpenCL 1.2 and 2.0 respectively and I've also verified that OpenCV successfully creates and uses an OpenCL context. Any thoughts on how I could get cv::ogl::mapGLBuffer() working to copy the OpenGL buffer to an OpenCL UMat?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I got OpenCV interop with OpenGL (and also VAAPI) working was by [forking OpenCV 4.x](https://github.com/kallaballa/opencv/tree/GCV). I also wrote [two demos](https://github.com/kallaballa/GCV) based on my fixes.
There are two github issues addressing my efforts:

- [OpenGL/OpenCL and VAAPI/OpenCL interop at the same time](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22607)
- [Capture MJPEG from V4l2 using VAAPI hardware acceleration to OpenCL
  using VAAPI/OpenCL interop](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/22622)